# one enter keypress runs JavaScript keypress event handler code twice

Tags: javascript

Why does one enter `keypress` run through this code twice?
I've tried `keypress`, `keydown` and also `event.preventdefault()` to no avail.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
       alert("0")
        var focado = document.getElementById(document.activeElement.id), fim = focado.id.substring(1),
            inicio = focado.id.substring(0, 1),
            fimseg = fim,
            anterior = inicio + (fim - 1),

        alert("1")


        alert("focado " + focado.id + " fim " + fim + " inicio " + inicio + " fimseg " + fimseg + " anterior " + anterior);
    }
});
```

Only after giving these 3 messages twice would it continue to the remaining code (not shown).

**UPDATE:**

This is the full program:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {

        var focado = document.getElementById(document.activeElement.id), fim = focado.id.substring(1),
            inicio = focado.id.substring(0, 1),
            fimseg = fim,
            anterior = inicio + (fim - 1),
            seguinte = focado;


        switch (fim) {
            case "1":
                fimseg = "2"
                break;
            case "2":
                fimseg = "3"
                break;
            case "3":
                fimseg = "4"
                break;
            case "4":
                fimseg = "5"
                break;
        }
      seguinte = inicio + (fimseg);

        if (seguinte == "p5") {
            seguinte = "a1";
        }

        alert("focado " + focado.id + " fim " + fim + " inicio " + inicio + " fimseg " + fimseg + " anterior " + anterior + " seguinte " + seguinte);

        if (focado.value.length == 0) {//enter no vazio

           alert("aqui")
            if (fim != 1) {//se não é p1 nem a1
                alert("1")
                if (document.getElementById(anterior).value.length == 0) {//se anterior vazio
                    alert("2")
                    document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                } else {//se anterior não vazio
                    alert("3")
                    if (seguinte == "a5") {//se é a4
                        alert("4")
                        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                    } else {//se nºao é a4
                        alert("5")
                        document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()
                    }
                }

            } else {//é p1 ou a1

                document.getElementById(focado.id).focus()  //foca no próprio

            }
        } else {
                            if (focado.value.length < 7 || (isNaN(focado.value))) {

                document.getElementById(focado.id).innerHtml = "";
                if (anterior.value.length == 0) {

                    document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                } else {

                    document.getElementById(focado.id).focus()
                }
            } else {

                if (fim != 1) { //não é p1 nem a1


                    if (document.getElementById(anterior).value.length ==0) {

                        document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                    } else {

                        if (seguinte == "a5") {

                            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                        } else {

                            document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()

                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()

                }
            }
        }
    } //não é enter
}); //fim função
```

When it gets to

```
if (focado.value.length == 0)
```

it goes back to the first variable declaration.  This is a problem because that way the variables `fimseg` and `seguinte` begin that cycle with the wrong values.

Comment: Does this behaviour persist you replace `alert()` by `console.log()`?

Comment: Your example code has a syntax error. Please provide the full code so anyone could reproduce your actual error.

Comment: it doesnt trigger more than once. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/425/. but you're missing semicolons everywhere (also fixed in the demo)

Comment: i've added an update with the full code.  missing semicolons on the trimmed code.
@Halcyon : alerts are just my debug helper

Comment: that switch block is just because i couldn't do this:
 seguinte = inicio + (fim +1);
           with sum instead of concatenate (fim +1)
I've tried seguinte = inicio + (parse(fim) +1); and seguinte = inicio + (parseInt(fim) +1); but they throwed errors
if I can make this sum work I can avoid the switch block and the function will probably work.

Comment: I managed to do it with parsefloat() but the error continues.

when it evaluates    if (focado.value.length == 0)    
begins again saying the focus is in the next input field.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a syntax error. Even when I include the `});` that was not properly code-wrapped in your question, I still get this error in my Firebug console:

```
SyntaxError: missing ;
before statement alert("1") <----
```

Try creating a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/. Then we can help you more.

**EDIT:**

OK, I looked at your jsfiddle. Based on your comment, I think the main problems are:

- It sounds like this is meant to be some sort of client-side validation script. But you don't explain exactly what it is supposed to do if the input is valid, or invalid. I'm going to assume that you want a popup message either way. I think it makes more sense to separate the "jump to the next empty box" behavior from the "validate and submit the values" behavior. So I did that in two separate handlers.
- If you focus on the button (e.g. by tabbing to it, or pressing it down but moving the mouse away before releasing the mouse button) and then press Enter, you will get an error because the ID of the button does not match the expected pattern of the ID's you've set for the text boxes. So I changed the button to act the same as an Enter keypress on the first (top-left text box.) And I called [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent it from bubbling up to the document Enter handler.
- I updated the Enter handler to only work on the textboxes, because you would get an error if you focus on just the document body or the button and then press Enter.

Here is the updated, working code: https://jsfiddle.net/op96m1Ln/2/. I use parseInt to capture the current box and some simple logic to jump to the next box in order. I also use regular expressions to validate the input.

Comment: tried to create a sample on jsfiddle but it does nothing...

https://jsfiddle.net/mehrlicht/bro0nwmo/

Comment: that switch block is just because i couldn't do this:
 seguinte = inicio + (fim +1);
           with sum instead of concatenate (fim +1)
I've tried seguinte = inicio + (parse(fim) +1); and seguinte = inicio + (parseInt(fim) +1); but they throwed errors
if I can make this sum work I can avoid the switch block and the function will probably work.

Comment: @mehrlicht Check out this fiddle that indubitablee created based on your original sample: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/425. It works fine once you add the semi-colons. As for your new code, what is it supposed to be doing? The code is totally different from before. What do you expect to happen? Note that you have to press Ctrl+Enter to run the fiddle, then click in the bottom-right Result window to use it.

Comment: I managed to do it with parsefloat() but the error continues.

when it evaluates    if (focado.value.length == 0)    
begins again saying the focus is in the next input field.

Comment: @mehrlicht Again: Exactly what do you expect to happen? Describe in words what you want the code to do. (These words may take many minutes to write, even over an hour, for a proper explanation. That's OK! The requirements are more important than the code!) Then describe what happens instead. (And remember to include *how* you get the bad behavior -- are you still pressing Enter? Which control has focus when you press Enter?) We need more details to help you. We can't debug a shell of a program without knowing exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: the aim is to click the submit button and send the textbox values.
before that it navigates between the textboxes.
First the boxes on the left and then the ones on the right.
Must be 7 or 8 digits on the left and 7 on the right.
At least one box on each column must be filled.
if enter is pressed on an empty box it jumps to the next field (according to the rules above)

Comment: i'm pressing the enter on the first textbox on the left. it runs correctly until the evaluation 
 if (focado.value.length == 0)    
but than returns to the variables declaration saying it catched the keypress on the second box on the left

Comment: I was mistaken.
It goes correctly to the last else. focus on the second box on the left.
and then catches a new enter keypress

Comment: ok.
On jfiddle your code didn't work as I wanted. Enter on an empty p2, p3 or p4, should jump to a1 and not the next one. for example.
Also, the validation shouls be done on the input box keypress (primary aim is to be used with barcodes) and this is a very mechanical task so it should be corrected right there and not after 8 codes.

What I did:
I took your advice (and despite pressing enter outside the boxes not giving me errors) and changed $(document).keydown to $("input[type=text]").keydown

And this is way it workd. no repeating cycle!

Thanks for putting me in the right track ;-)

Comment: @mehrlicht You're welcome. Please upvote and/or mark accepted the answer if it helped. Or create your own answer with the full solution. You may also want to consider editing your question as the original problem you described is no longer relevant.